# Python: replace a rgb colour with a colour with alpha pixels. batch convert 400 images

Tags: python, image, colors, replace

How can I replace a colour across multiple images with another in python? I have a folder with 400 sprite animations. I would like to change the block coloured shadow (111,79,51) with one which has alpha transparencies. I could easily do the batch converting using:

```
img = glob.glob(filepath\*.bmp)
```

however I dont know how I could change the pixel colours. If it makes any difference, the images are all 96x96 and i dont care how long the process is. I am using python 3.2.2 so I cant really use PIL (I think)

Comment: Have you tried the unofficial PIL build for Python 3.2 ? http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. If it doesn't work, I would also give a shot to opencv ;)

Comment: Have you considered using ImageMagick?

Comment: thanks! i diddnt know about the unofficial PIL for 3.2.2, working great now!

Answer (score 0):

BMP is a windows file format, so you will need PIL or something like it; or you can roll your own reader/writer.  The basic modules won't help as far as I'm aware.  You can read PPM and GIF using Tk (PhotoImage()) which is part of the standard distribution and use get() and put() on that image to change pixel values.  See references online, because it's not straight-forward - the pixels come from get() as 3-tuple integers, but need to go back to put() as space-separated hex text!

Answer (score 0):

Are your images in indexed mode (8 bit per pixel with a palette),or "truecolor" 32bpp images? If they are in indexed modes, it would not be hard to simply mark the palette entry for that color to be transparent across all files.

Otherwise, you will really have to process all pixel data. It also could be done by writting a Python script for GIMP - but that would require Python-2 nonetheless.